# CodeBlocks, environment variables path added, but g++ error outside the installation folder?

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks

I have just installed the CodeBlocks to compile c++ programs,
The path where this is installed is,

```
      C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin
```

I have also added this path to the Environment Variables path,

The g++ command works fine from command prompt, inside this folder,

```
     g++: fatal error: no input files
          compilation terminated
```

but when i give the g++ command outside this folder, it gives me an error,

```
     'g++' is not recognized as an external or internal command,
        operable program or batch file
```

My question is, why i am getting this error, even after i have added the path to the environment variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably added the wrong path.

Comment: I have checked again, i have added the correct path, is there anything else which i missed during the setup ?

Comment: start `cmd`. What is the output of `path`?